# xpath trying to select content inside a div except one, with text included

Tags: xpath

Im trying to select the content inside a div, this div has some text inside and some additional tags. I dont want to select the first div inside. I was trying with this selector, but only gives me the tags, without text

```
//div[@class='contentDealDescriptionFacts cf']/div[@class='viewHalfWidthSize' and position()=2]/*[not(@class='subHeadline')]
```

the div that is giving me problems is this one:

```
<div class="viewHalfWidthSize">
    .......
</div>

<div class="viewHalfWidthSize">
    <div class="subHeadline firefinder-match">The Fine Print</div> <----------Except this div I want everything inside of this div!!
    <strong class="firefinder-match">Validity: </strong>
    Expires 27 June 2013.
    <br class="firefinder-match">
    <strong class="firefinder-match">Purchase: </strong>
    Limit 1 per 2 people. May buy multiple as gifts.
    <br class="firefinder-match">
    <strong class="firefinder-match">Redemption: </strong>
    Booking required online at
    <a target="_blank" href="http://grouponbookings.co.uk/lautre-pied-march/"      class="firefinder-match">http://grouponbookings.co.uk/lautre-pied-march/</a>
. 48-hour cancellation policy; late cancellation incurs a £30 surcharge per person.
    <br class="firefinder-match">
    <strong class="firefinder-match">Further information: </strong>
    Valid Mon-Sun midday-2.45pm; Mon-Wed 6pm-10.45pm. Must be 18 or older, ID may be   requested. Valid only on set tasting menu only; menu is dependent on market changes and seasonality and is subject to change. Max. two hours seating time. Discretionary service charge will be added to the bill based on original price. Original value verified 19 March 2013 at 9.01am.
   <br class="firefinder-match">
   <a target="_blank" href="http://www.groupon.co.uk/universal-fine-print" style="color: #339933;" class="firefinder-match">See the rules</a>
that apply to all deals.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `*` matches element nodes and not text nodes. Try replacing `*` with `node()` to select all node types.

To break down what your XPath is doing:

You are looking anywhere in the document (`//`) for a div with class 'contentDealDescriptionFacts cf'.

Then you are looking for the 2nd div under that which also has the class `viewHalfWidthSize`. Note, this is not the 2nd div that has the class but the div that is 2nd AND has that class, so if the divs with that class are the 3rd and 4th it wouldn't match anything as the 2nd div with the class has `position() = 4`. If you want the 2nd `viewHalfWidthSize` div then you'll want `[@class='viewHalfWidthSize'][position()=2]`.

Finally, you are returning a nodelist of all elements without the class `subHeadline`. If you change the `*` to `node()` then you will get a nodelist of all nodes.

---

The following XPath:

```
//div[@class='contentDealDescriptionFacts cf']/div[@class='viewHalfWidthSize' and position()=2]/node()[not(name(.)='div' and position() = 1)]
```

should return what you want as long as the first child node is the div you want to ignore.

If you change it to:

```
//div[@class='contentDealDescriptionFacts cf']/div[@class='viewHalfWidthSize' and position()=2]/node()[position() != count(../div[1]/preceding-sibling::node()) + 1]
```

then it should work regardless. It returns your nodelist, then works out how many preceding nodes there are before the first div, and checks the position isn't one greater than that (i.e. position of first div) and excludes that from the list.

---

As yet another alternative you could just modify your original solution but instead of doing `not(@class='subHeadline')` you should do

```
not(contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' subHeadline '))
```

which will check if the class attribute contains `subHeadline` anywhere in the string on the assumption that your classes are space separated. This would then match your fragment which has the class `"subHeadline firefinder-match"`

Comment: no.......I tried, but thanks!. //div[@class='contentDealDescriptionFacts cf']/div[@class='viewHalfWidthSize' and position()=2]/node()  the selector was empty

Comment: Check the XPath bit by bit to check what it is matching. See my edit about the position in case that's your problem - using 2 predicates instead of a combined one.

Comment: yes, really im trying with an interactive selector (firefinder for xpath), up the the div I show here (the main) everything is fine, the problem is the last step...

Comment: Added a couple of solutions now I've tested it in an evaluator. Your solution wasn't matching as the full attribute is subHeadline firefinder-match and not just subHeadline. You still would need node() instead of *, and I assume the position() = 2 was to pick out the fragment you posted and not related to ignoring the first div?

Comment: im going to modify the problem to add a little more of context. Thanks!

Comment: That's fine, you can re-add the `position() = 2` to the second div selector. I'll amend my answer.